# Combinations in a range of numbers in C++

Tags: c++, combinations, combinatorics

I would like to build a C++ program that show all the possible combinations depending on the number of elements taken by a N factor.

Let's suppose a vector vec[6] with elements 1 2 3 4 5 6 on it.
Using the combination formula, 6! / 4! (6 - 4)! = 15 possibilities
I want to  generate a function which gives the result of all 15 possibilities taken 4 by 4 with no repetition, as example:
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 5
1 2 3 6
2 3 4 5
and so on...

I am using this code for now, but i want to use numbers from my vector (v[6]).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void comb(int N, int K)
{
    std::string bitmask(K, 1); // K leading 1's
    bitmask.resize(N, 0); // N-K trailing 0's

    // print integers and permute bitmask
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // [0..N-1] integers
        {
            if (bitmask[i]) std::cout << " " << i;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));
}

int main()
{
    comb(6, 4);
}
```

Would you please guys give me a help? I'd like to know where i could change the code so that i can use my own vector.

i'm generating this vector v[i] and sorting it with a bubble sort, like this:

```
void order (int d[], int n){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
            if (d[j] > d[j+1])
                swap (d[j],d[j+1]);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << d[i] << " ";
}
```

after that sorting, i want to put my vector into the comb function.
how could i make it is possible?

Comment: Replace `std::cout << " " << i` with `std::cout << " " << v[i]`?

Comment: my intention is to make a function passing a vector of numbers and not a number, like that:
void order(int d[], int K){}

Answer (score 3):

Here's a C++14 solution that uses a [free, open source library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html) to do the work:

```
#include "combinations"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int state = 0;
    for_each_combination(v.begin(), v.begin() + 4, v.end(),
        [&state](auto first, auto last)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << ++state << " : ";
            while (true)
            {
                std::cout << *first;
                if (++first == last)
                    break;
                std::cout << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
            return false;
        });
}
```

This outputs:

```
 1 : 1 2 3 4
 2 : 1 2 3 5
 3 : 1 2 3 6
 4 : 1 2 4 5
 5 : 1 2 4 6
 6 : 1 2 5 6
 7 : 1 3 4 5
 8 : 1 3 4 6
 9 : 1 3 5 6
10 : 1 4 5 6
11 : 2 3 4 5
12 : 2 3 4 6
13 : 2 3 5 6
14 : 2 4 5 6
15 : 3 4 5 6
```

The source code for the library can be copy/pasted from the above link and inspected for how it works.  This library is *extremely* high performance compared to solutions using `std::prev_permutation`.  The implementation is relatively simple for this function, but the library also contains more functionality that grows increasingly complicated to implement (but just as easy to use):

```
template <class BidirIter, class Function>
Function
for_each_combination(BidirIter first,
                     BidirIter mid,
                     BidirIter last,
                     Function f);

template <class BidirIter, class Function>
Function
for_each_permutation(BidirIter first,
                     BidirIter mid,
                     BidirIter last,
                     Function f);

template <class BidirIter, class Function>
Function
for_each_reversible_permutation(BidirIter first,
                                BidirIter mid,
                                BidirIter last,
                                Function f);

template <class BidirIter, class Function>
Function
for_each_circular_permutation(BidirIter first,
                              BidirIter mid,
                              BidirIter last,
                              Function f);

template <class BidirIter, class Function>
Function
for_each_reversible_circular_permutation(BidirIter first,
                                         BidirIter mid,
                                         BidirIter last,
                                         Function f);
```

The library has several pleasant features including:

- Your input sequence (`vector` or whatever) need not be sorted.
- You can prematurely break out of the loop at any time by returning `true`.
- If you don't break out of the loop early, the sequence is always returned to its original state.
- The functor always receives iterators to the first `k` elements of the sequence, so it is possible to also operate on the elements *not selected* if you tell the functor about the total length of the sequence.

Feel free to use the library as is, or study and take what you need from its implementation.  The link above contains a tutorial-like description, and a detailed specification of each function.

Comment: has this been proposed for standardization, or is it somewhere on your todo list?

Comment: It has not been proposed for standardization.  It was presented to the LWG about 5 years ago.  I'm not sure it passes the test of "widely needed."  I'm also unsure how to specify it such that it is **fast**.  These functions are useless if not orders of magnitude faster than things like next_permutation.

Answer (score 0):

Start with subset S = {1,2,3,...,k}, that's the first subset.  Generate the next subset by examining elements from the right (start with the last), and increment it if you can (if it is < N), and return that as the next subset.  If you can't increment it, look at the element to the left until you find one you can increment.  Increment it, and set the elements to the right sequentially from that point.  Below are the 3 element subsets of {1,2,3,4,5} (N=5,k=3,there are 10 subsets):

{1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,2,5}, {1,3,4}, {1,3,5}, {1,4,5}, {2,3,4}, {2,3,5}, {2,4,5}, {3,4,5}

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, std::vector<int>& a)
{
    o << "{";
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
        o << *it;
        if (it + 1 < a.end()) o << ",";
    }
    return o << "}";
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 7;
    const int k = 4;

    std::vector<int> A(k);

    // initialize
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        A[i] = i + 1;
    }

    std::cout << A << std::endl;
    int h = 0;
    bool done = false;
    do {
        ++A[k-h-1];
        for (int t = k - h; t < k; ++t) {
            A[t] = A[t-1] + 1;
        }
        if (A[k-h-1] < N - h) {
            // last element can be incremented, stay there...
            h = 0;
        } else {
            // last element at max, look back ...
            ++h;
        }
        done = (A[0] == N - k + 1);
        std::cout << A << std::endl;    
    } while (!done);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple recursive implementation:

```
struct Combs
{
    vector<int> scombs;

    template <typename F>
    void call_combs(int n, int k, F f)
    {
        if (k == 0) {
            f();
        }
        else {
            scombs.push_back(n - 1);
            call_combs(n - 1, k - 1, f);
            scombs.resize(scombs.size() - 1);
            if (k < n) {
                call_combs(n - 1, k, f);
            }
        }
    }
};

...

    Combs combs;
    const auto& coco = combs.scombs;
    combs.call_combs(6, 4, [&coco](){
        copy(coco.cbegin(), coco.cend(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout));
        cout << endl;
    });
```